# When I tried the Live CD, my multiple monitor setup worked. After I installed, it didn't. What gives?

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, multiple-monitors

I just installed Ubuntu 11.10 x64, after making sure I could use my 2-monitor setup with the Live CD, but now Ubuntu cannot detect both my monitors. I've tried both of the Additional Drivers that Ubuntu offers, and neither helps. I've got a PNY GTS 250 1GB card with 2 DVI monitors hooked up, if that helps.

Here's a screenshot of my Display Settings screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/47G83.png

Any ideas on how to get it working like I did with the Live CD? Or why it was working from the Live CD but won't work now that I've installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the LiveCD you were using the free Nouveau driver. Generally worse performance but you do get KMS and `xrandr` works.

But now, you're probably on the closed source driver which does offer better performance (especially in 3d) and better power settings and scaling. All you need to do is run `nvidia-settings` (there's probably an entry in the dash) and edit your settings from within there.

If it's not installed, just search for it in the Software Center.

Comment: Brilliant! Typing nvidia-settings into the dash brought up NVIDIA X Server Settings, where I could set up both monitors under X Server Display Configuration. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: It's even worse and I can't get both monitors using nvidia-settings on 12.04. How do I uninstall the Nvidia driver and use the Nouveau like the Live CD?

Comment: Actually, I just found out how to elsewhere, but I'll put the answer here so future Googlers can see it.

1. Reboot.

2. At the login, hold Control and Alt and press F2.

3. Log in, then type these commands one at a time:

    `sudo su`
    `apt-get purge nvidia-current`
    `rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf`
    `reboot now`

Comment: @Kerrick this might be a temporal issue with the current 295.40 version of the Nvidia driver. It has a few very horrible performance bugs that span several generations of hardware in different circumstances. When they've finally updated that, the closed Nvidia driver might be better for you.